# why my map function adding additionally 2 empty 'li''s?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending a drop down menu on the text input, i have the gender as male, and female i am just adding this in my li's while it get foucs. but i am getting additionally 2 empty li's on focus.. why?

this is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var  gender = ['Female','Male'],
      genderField = $('#gender');

   var genderUpdate= function(){
            genderField.focus(function(){
                if(!$('#genderList').length){
                    var topPos = $(this).position().top,lftPos = $(this).position().left;
                    $('<ul id="genderList"></ul>').css({
                        position    :'absolute',
                        top         : topPos,
                        left        : lftPos
                    }).appendTo($(this).parent());


                    $.map(gender,function(val,i){
                        $('<li>'+val+'<li>').appendTo('#genderList');
                        console.log('append');
                    })

                }


            })
        }

                        genderUpdate();

})
```

here is the fiddle :

[visit the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85DM4/1/)

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the difference ;=)

```
$('<li>'+val+'<li>').appendTo('#genderList');

$('<li>'+val+'</li>').appendTo('#genderList');
```

The browser has been "nice" and automatically closed your unclosed li tags, two on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: clever. very thanks. some time it's happening very silly things. thanks for your identity.